# looping through a collection of divs in Watir

Tags: xpath, watir

We're using watir for testing and wondered how to select a group of divs that meet a particular criteria?  In our case the (simplified) html looks like this:

```
<div class="month_main>
 <div class="month_cell">
   some divs
 </div>
 <div class="month_cell">
   some_other_divs
 </div>
 <div class = "month_cell OverridenDay">
   <div id = "month-2013-05-04"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

We would like to loop through all divs with an id starting with 'month' that are contained in `month_cell` parent divs that also have classes of `OverridenDay`.  Is there an Xpath or regular expression we can use in conjunction with the Watir browser class to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**General**

You can get a collection of elements in a similar way to getting a single element. You basically need to pluralize the element type method. For example:

```
#Singular method returns first matching div
browser.div

#Pluralized method returns all matching divs
browser.divs
```

Collections can be used using the same locators as single elements.

**Solution**

For your problem, you can do:

```
#Iterate over divs that have the class 'month_cell OverridenDay'
browser.divs(:class => 'month_cell OverridenDay').each do |overridden_div|

    #Within each div with class 'month_cell OverridenDay',
    #  iterate over any children divs where the id starts with month
    overridden_div.divs(:id => /^month/).each do |div|

        #Do something with the div that has id starting with month
        puts div.id

    end
end
#=> "month-2013-05-0"
```

If you need to create a single collection that includes all of the matching divs, you will need to use a css or xpath selector.

Using a css-selector (note that in watir-webdriver, only the elements method supports css-locators):

```
divs = browser.elements(:css => 'div.month_cell.OverridenDay div[id^=month]')
divs.each do |e|
    puts e.id
end 
#=> "month-2013-05-0"
```

Using xpath:

```
divs = browser.divs(:xpath => '//div[@class="month_cell OverridenDay"]//div[starts-with(@id, "month")]')
divs.each do |e|
    puts e.id
end
#=> "month-2013-05-0"
```

Comment: what if they are not <div>s?

Comment: @Phlip , you would use the `ElementCollection` method for whichever tag you're working with. In general, it is the plural form of the tag name. For example, `span` is `#spans`, `summary` is `#summaries`. You can see a full list of methods in the documentation at https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Container.